# Google Sheets - Script to move columns given the column header

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Given this table schema:

| Col_France | Col_Argentina | Col_Croatia | Col_Morocco |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | x |
| x | x | x | x |

I want to create a `Google Script` that rearranges the columns so the order is always:

```
Col_Argentina -> Column 1
Col_France -> Column 2
Col_Croatia -> Column 3
Col_Morocco -> Column 4
```

Because the original column orders of the given table is not always as described above, I cannot simply use:

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
// Selects Col_France.
var columnSpec = sheet.getRange("A1");
sheet.moveColumns(columnSpec, 2);
```

and so on... In other words, the table schema can possibly be:

| Col_Morocco | Col_Croatia | Col_France | Col_Argentina |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | x | x | x |
| x | x | x | x |

but the desired outcome should always be the defined above. The script should be scalable. In the future, more than 4 columns should be rearranged.

My approach would be:

- Define the range of columns to rearrange (they are all together)
- For the first column, get the value of the column header
- Depending on the value, move the column to a predefined index
- Move to the next column and repeat
- Iterate until end of range

Can somebody please point me to the required functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your situation, when `moveColumns` is used, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var order = ["Col_Argentina", "Col_France", "Col_Croatia", "Col_Morocco"]; // This is from your question.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var obj = sheet.getRange(1, 1, 1, sheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].reduce((ar, h, i) => [...ar, { from: i + 1, to: order.indexOf(h) + 1 }], []).sort((a, b) => a.to > b.to ? 1 : -1);
  for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
    if (obj[i].from != obj[i].to) {
      sheet.moveColumns(sheet.getRange(1, obj[i].from), obj[i].to);
      obj.forEach((e, j) => {
        if (e.from < obj[i].from) obj[j].from += 1;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

- When this script is run, the columns are rearranged by `order` you give. In this case, the text and cell format are also moved.
- When `moveColumns(columnSpec, destinationIndex)` is used, the indexes of columns are changed after `moveColumns(columnSpec, destinationIndex)` was run. So, please be careful about this. In the above script, the changed indexes are considered.

#### References:

- [moveColumns(columnSpec, destinationIndex)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#moveColumns(Range,Integer))
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [forEach()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Answer (score 1):

Order Columns:

```
function ordercols() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [h,...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const idx = {};
  h.forEach((h,i) => idx[h]=i);
  const o = vs.map(r => [r[idx['COL4']],r[idx['COL3']],r[idx['COL2']],r[idx['COL1']]]);
  sh.clearContents();
  o.unshift(['COL4','COL3','COL2','COL1']);
  sh.getRange(1,1,o.length,o[0].length).setValues(o);
}
```

Data:

| COL1 | COL2 | COL3 | COL4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24 | 5 | 2 | 9 |
| 16 | 0 | 13 | 18 |
| 22 | 24 | 23 | 16 |
| 12 | 12 | 4 | 17 |
| 6 | 20 | 17 | 14 |
| 7 | 13 | 4 | 2 |
| 2 | 20 | 4 | 22 |
| 3 | 5 | 3 | 4 |
| 16 | 5 | 7 | 23 |

ReOrdered:

| COL4 | COL3 | COL2 | COL1 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | 2 | 5 | 24 |
| 18 | 13 | 0 | 16 |
| 16 | 23 | 24 | 22 |
| 17 | 4 | 12 | 12 |
| 14 | 17 | 20 | 6 |
| 2 | 4 | 13 | 7 |
| 22 | 4 | 20 | 2 |
| 4 | 3 | 5 | 3 |
| 23 | 7 | 5 | 16 |