# Script to move data from columns in order based on comparison of two linear headers

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

## How it looks

- This is **the first row with headers** (with its own order):

  | Name | Rank | Year | Gender |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**The second row** is empty.

- This is **the table starting from the third row with headers** (with a different order of headers than the first row):

  | Rank | Year | Gender | Name |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | 5 | 1991 | Male | Henry |
  | 3 | 1992 | Female | Amelia |
  | 1 | 1993 | Male | Jack |
  | 2 | 1994 | Female | Luna |
  | 4 | 1995 | Male | Oliver |

## How it should look

**Table headers** must match the order of **the first row headers**. But when moving columns, only the data after the table headers should be affected.

Ultimately it should be like this:

- **The first row** remains as is:

  | Name | Rank | Year | Gender |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**The second row** is empty.

- **The table** is like this:

  | Rank | Year | Gender | Name |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | Henry | 5 | 1991 | Male |
  | Amelia | 3 | 1992 | Female |
  | Jack | 1 | 1993 | Male |
  | Luna | 2 | 1994 | Female |
  | Oliver | 4 | 1995 | Male |

This may seem strange, but it is necessary.

## What I tried

- **Function** in Apps Script:

  ```
  function moveColumns() {

  var ACTIVE_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var ORDER = ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(1,1,1,ACTIVE_SHEET.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var OBJECT = ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(3,1,1,ACTIVE_SHEET.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0].reduce((ar, h, i) => [...ar, { from: i + 1, to: ORDER.indexOf(h) + 1 }], []).sort((a, b) => a.to > b.to ? 1 : -1);

  for (var i = 0; i < OBJECT.length; i++) {
    if (OBJECT[i].from != OBJECT[i].to) {
      ACTIVE_SHEET.moveColumns(ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(1,OBJECT[i].from),OBJECT[i].to);
      OBJECT.forEach((e, j) => {
        if (e.from < OBJECT[i].from) OBJECT[j].from += 1;
        });
      }
    }

  }
  ```

**After running the script** it looks like this:

- **The first row** is like this:

  | Gender | Name | Rank | Year |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |

**The second row** is empty.

- **The table** is like this:

  | Name | Rank | Year | Gender |
  | --- | --- | --- | --- |
  | Henry | 5 | 1991 | Male |
  | Amelia | 3 | 1992 | Female |
  | Jack | 1 | 1993 | Male |
  | Luna | 2 | 1994 | Female |
  | Oliver | 4 | 1995 | Male |

**Related question:**

- [Script to move columns given the column header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74856550/google-sheets-script-to-move-columns-given-the-column-header)

Comment: I asked a similar question because in the previous one I did not take into account some conditions. [Link to question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78119264/script-to-move-data-from-columns-in-order-based-on-comparison-of-two-linear-head).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In the current stage, when the columns are moved with `moveColumns`, all rows are moved. I think that this is the reason for your current issue.
- From your showing script, I guessed that in your actual situation, you might want to move the cell values with the cell styles.

If my guess is correct, how about the following modification?

#### Modified script:

```js
function moveColumns() {
  var ACTIVE_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var range = ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(1, 1, 3, ACTIVE_SHEET.getLastColumn());
  var headers = range.getValues();
  var styles = range.getTextStyles();
  var backgrounds = range.getBackgrounds();
  var [ORDER, , header2] = headers;
  var OBJECT = header2.reduce((ar, h, i) => [...ar, { from: i + 1, to: ORDER.indexOf(h) + 1 }], []).sort((a, b) => a.to > b.to ? 1 : -1);
  for (var i = 0; i < OBJECT.length; i++) {
    if (OBJECT[i].from != OBJECT[i].to) {
      ACTIVE_SHEET.moveColumns(ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(1, OBJECT[i].from), OBJECT[i].to);
      OBJECT.forEach((e, j) => {
        if (e.from < OBJECT[i].from) OBJECT[j].from += 1;
      });
    }
  }
  range.setValues(headers).setTextStyles(styles).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);
}
```

- In this case, the cell values, the text styles, and the backgrounds are kept before and after the columns are moved.
- This modification is by my guess. So, if you want to keep another format, please tell me.
- If you want to keep only the cell values, you can do it by modifying `range.setValues(headers).setTextStyles(styles).setBackgrounds(backgrounds);` to `range.setValues(headers);`.

### Added 1:

Although I'm not sure about `styles` of `I mean about the styles` you expect, how about the following modification? In this modification, the 3 header rows are kept by copying the original rows. About after row 4, the columns are moved with `moveColumns` by keeping the cell styles.

```js
function moveColumns() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var ACTIVE_SHEET = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var temp = ACTIVE_SHEET.copyTo(ss);
  var range = ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(1, 1, 3, ACTIVE_SHEET.getLastColumn());
  var headers = range.getValues();
  var [ORDER, , header2] = headers;
  var OBJECT = header2.reduce((ar, h, i) => [...ar, { from: i + 1, to: ORDER.indexOf(h) + 1 }], []).sort((a, b) => a.to > b.to ? 1 : -1);
  for (var i = 0; i < OBJECT.length; i++) {
    if (OBJECT[i].from != OBJECT[i].to) {
      ACTIVE_SHEET.moveColumns(ACTIVE_SHEET.getRange(1, OBJECT[i].from), OBJECT[i].to);
      OBJECT.forEach((e, j) => {
        if (e.from < OBJECT[i].from) OBJECT[j].from += 1;
      });
    }
  }
  temp.getRange(range.getA1Notation()).copyTo(range);
  ss.deleteSheet(temp);
}
```

Comment: This works, but when replacing, as indicated in the last point, the result of the script does not change (I mean about the styles).

Comment: @Stes Mus Thank you for replying. About `This works, but when replacing, as indicated in the last point, the result of the script does not change (I mean about the styles).`, what is your style? In my proposed script, the cell values, the text styles, and the backgrounds of the 3 header rows are kept before and after the columns are moved. What is your actual expected result? Can I ask you about the details of it? I think that when I can correctly understand your actual expected result, I can resolve my answer.

Comment: @Stes Mus Although I'm not sure about `styles` of `I mean about the styles` you expect, I added one more modified script. Please confirm it. If that was not useful, I apologize again. At that time, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Leave everything as is, the script works. Later, I'll create another question about the same problem (with more complexity), because it doesn't fit my project.

Comment: [My comment with a link to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78114986/script-to-move-data-from-columns-in-order-based-on-comparison-of-two-linear-head#comment137721568_78114986).

Answer (score 1):

Moving columns without headers:

```
function confuseData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const [h1, , h2, ...vs] = sh.getDataRange().getValues();
  const sidx = {};
  const didx = {};
  h2.forEach((h, i) => sidx[h] = i);//returns and  index
  h1.forEach((h, i) => didx[i] = h);//returns a header the headers must be the same
  let cvs = vs.map((r, i) => {
    let row = [];
    r.map((c, j) => {
      row.push(r[sidx[didx[j]]]);
    });
    return row;
  });
  sh.getRange(10, 1, cvs.length, cvs[0].length).setValues(cvs);///change starting row to 4 for real data
}
```

I moved  the output down to row 10 just for comparison sake

|  | A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Name | Rank | Year | Gender |
| 2 |  |  |  |  |
| 3 | Rank | Year | Gender | Name |
| 4 | 5 | 1991 | Male | Henry |
| 5 | 3 | 1992 | Female | Amelia |
| 6 | 1 | 1993 | Male | Jack |
| 7 | 2 | 1994 | Female | Luna |
| 8 | 4 | 1995 | Male | Olive |
| 9 |  |  |  |  |
| 10 | Henry | 5 | 1991 | Male |
| 11 | Amelia | 3 | 1992 | Female |
| 12 | Jack | 1 | 1993 | Male |
| 13 | Luna | 2 | 1994 | Female |
| 14 | Olive | 4 | 1995 | Male |

- [google-apps-script reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference)

Comment: That's right, but it would be desirable for styles to be transferred too. I understand that I didn't mention this in the question.