# Script to move data from columns in order based on comparison of two linear headers (with import formula)

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

## How it looks

I have a spreadsheet with two sheets:

- `Sheet1` contains the headers (**first and third rows**), let the names be `Headers 1` and `Headers 2`. **The second row** simply reveals the full name of the headers of **the third row**, i.e. `Headers 2` (it can also be blank).
- `Sheet2` contains **a table with data**, headers are imported from the first sheet via a formula.

#### Sheet1 (with headers on a separate sheet):

| RowNo | A (1) | B (2) | C (3) | D (4) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **(1)** | NM | RNK | YR | GNDR |
| **(2)** | Rank | Year | Gender | Name |
| **(3)** | RNK | YR | GNDR | NM |

In this case, `Headers 1` and `Headers 2` have different order.

#### Sheet2 (with the headers import formula):

| RowNo | C (3) | D (4) | E (5) | F (6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **(3)** | `=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","Sheet1!A1:D3")` |  |  |  |
| **(4)** |  |  |  |  |
| **(5)** |  |  |  |  |
| **(6)** | 5 | 1991 | Male | Henry |
| **(7)** | 3 | 1992 | Female | Amelia |
| **(8)** | 1 | 1993 | Male | Jack |
| **(9)** | 2 | 1994 | Female | Luna |
| **(10)** | 4 | 1995 | Male | Oliver |

#### Sheet2 (with headers after import):

| RowNo | C (3) | D (4) | E (5) | F (6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **(3)** | NM | RNK | YR | GNDR |
| **(4)** | Rank | Year | Gender | Name |
| **(5)** | RNK | YR | GNDR | NM |
| **(6)** | 5 | 1991 | Male | Henry |
| **(7)** | 3 | 1992 | Female | Amelia |
| **(8)** | 1 | 1993 | Male | Jack |
| **(9)** | 2 | 1994 | Female | Luna |
| **(10)** | 4 | 1995 | Male | Oliver |

As can be seen, **the table** can be located in different places, not necessarily in the first row and first column. There may be cells filled with other information behind **the table**.

## How it should look

- `Headers 2` should match the order of `Headers 1`. But when moving columns, only the data after `Headers 2` should be affected.
- The import formula must be untouched and not converted into plain text.

The result should be like this:

#### Sheet2 (with the headers import formula):

| RowNo | C (3) | D (4) | E (5) | F (6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **(3)** | `=IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","Sheet1!A1:D3")` |  |  |  |
| **(4)** |  |  |  |  |
| **(5)** |  |  |  |  |
| **(6)** | Henry | 5 | 1991 | Male |
| **(7)** | Amelia | 3 | 1992 | Female |
| **(8)** | Jack | 1 | 1993 | Male |
| **(9)** | Luna | 2 | 1994 | Female |
| **(10)** | Oliver | 4 | 1995 | Male |

#### Sheet2 (with headers):

| RowNo | C (3) | D (4) | E (5) | F (6) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **(3)** | NM | RNK | YR | GNDR |
| **(4)** | Rank | Year | Gender | Name |
| **(5)** | RNK | YR | GNDR | NM |
| **(6)** | Henry | 5 | 1991 | Male |
| **(7)** | Amelia | 3 | 1992 | Female |
| **(8)** | Jack | 1 | 1993 | Male |
| **(9)** | Luna | 2 | 1994 | Female |
| **(10)** | Oliver | 4 | 1995 | Male |

#### Previous related question:

- [Script to move data from columns in order based on comparison of two linear headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78114986/script-to-move-data-from-columns-in-order-based-on-comparison-of-two-linear-head)

Comment: About your question, are you required to consider the cell style (background colors and text style) before and after the columns are moved? Or, do you want to move only the cell values?

Comment: @Tanaike Not entirely necessary, because my other script completely does the template formatting for the range of all values located after the table headers. But it would be great if this can be done.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your reply, I cannot imagine your actual expected result. Can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect including the style? First, I have to correctly understand your actual expected result. I deeply apologize that I am trying to correctly understand your actual expected result.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm using a translator :) I have corrected the question and removed this requirement. In the previous question the move works, but if I use the import formula and a different table location with data behind the table, it doesn't.

Comment: Thank you for replying. From your reply, I proposed 2 patterns. Please confirm it. If those were not your actual expected result, I apologize. By the way, my answer supposes that `(3)` of `(3) =IMPORTRANGE("spreadsheet_url","Sheet1!A1:D3")` is row 3. Please be careful about this.

Comment: Sorry. Now, I noticed that the upper left cell of your "Sheet2" was "C3". So, I modified it. Please confirm it.

Comment: @Tanaike Sorry, I corrected it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your following reply,

> Not entirely necessary, because my other script completely does the template formatting for the range of all values located after the table headers. But it would be great if this can be done.

How about the following 2 patterns?

#### Pattern 1:

This pattern moves only cell values.

```js
function myFunction1() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn() - 2);
  const [header1, , header2, ...v] = range.getValues();
  const convertHeader = header1.map(h => header2.indexOf(h));
  const res = v.map(r => convertHeader.map(i => r[i]));
  range.offset(3, 0, res.length, res[0].length).setValues(res);
}
```

#### Pattern 2:

This pattern moves cell values, text styles, backgrounds, and number formats.

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet2"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const range = sheet.getRange(3, 3, sheet.getLastRow() - 2, sheet.getLastColumn() - 2);
  const [header1, , header2, ...v] = range.getValues();
  const valueRange = range.offset(3, 0, v.length, v[0].length);
  const textStyles = valueRange.getTextStyles();
  const backgrounds = valueRange.getBackgrounds();
  const numberFormats = valueRange.getNumberFormats();
  const convertHeader = header1.map(h => header2.indexOf(h));
  const [newValues, newTextStyles, newBackgrounds, newNumberFormats] = [v, textStyles, backgrounds, numberFormats].map(e => e.map(r => convertHeader.map(i => r[i])));
  valueRange.setValues(newValues).setTextStyles(newTextStyles).setBackgrounds(newBackgrounds).setNumberFormats(newNumberFormats);
}
```

Comment: Yes, pattern 1 is correct, but when dates and numbers are moved, they are converted into other data. Those: Col1: 2009 -> Col2: 1905-07-01 / Col1: 2009-05-26 -> Col2: 26.05.2009.

Comment: Pattern 2 fixes this, but it takes longer to work with a massive table. If you know how to fix this in Pattern 1, please write.

Comment: @Stes Mus Thank you for replying. About `Yes, pattern 1 is correct, but when dates and numbers are moved, they are converted into other data. Those: Col1: 2009 -> Col2: 1905-07-01 / Col1: 2009-05-26 -> Col2: 26.05.2009.` and `Pattern 2 fixes this`, I think that the reason for this issue is due to the number format. In the case of pattern 2, the number format is also copied. By this, the issue was resolved. And, I understood that your issue was resolved.

Comment: @Stes Mus About `but it takes longer to work with a massive table.`, unfortunately, I cannot know your actual situation. But, I would like to support you. So, can you post it as a new question by including more information? By this, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Stes Mus About `but it takes longer to work with a massive table.`, when you post it as a new question, please include the size of the Spreadsheet. For example, in your this question, the range with the values is "C3:F10". When you include the range with the values of `but it takes longer to work with a massive table.`, it will help users including me think of a solution. If you can cooperate to resolve your new issue, I'm glad. Can you cooperate to do it?

Comment: @Stes Mus As one simple modification, from `Yes, pattern 1 is correct` and `Pattern 2 fixes this`, for example, when you modify the pattern 2 as follows? From `valueRange.setValues(newValues).setTextStyles(newTextStyles).setBackgrounds(newBackgrounds).setNumberFormats(newNumberFormats);` to `valueRange.setValues(newValues).setNumberFormats(newNumberFormats);`? In this case, the cell values and the number formats are used. But, the process cost can be reduced. But, if this was not useful for your actual situation, can you post it as a new question?

Comment: I removed the unnecessary stuff as you wrote - it works quite quickly. Thanks for your help, I don't think another question is needed.